# Tabulator 5.0 Reference Error on tabEndNewRow

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I want to use the function `tabEndNewRow` to create a new row and jump into the outer left cell but I get the following error message:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: nav is not defined
    at Edit.js:91
```

The new row is created but the focus is not set on the wanted cell in the new row. I used `tabEndNewRow` in version 4.9 without any problems. Here's the code I used to test the behaviour of `tabEndNewRow` of both versions:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <!-- Tabulator 5.0-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="tabulator-master_5_0/dist/css/tabulator.css">
    </style>
    <script src="tabulator-master_5_0/dist/js/tabulator.js"></script>

    <!-- Tabulator 4.9-->
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="tabulator-master_4_9/dist/css/tabulator.css"></style> -->
    <!-- <script src="tabulator-master_4_9/dist/js/tabulator.js"></script> -->

</head>

<body>
    <div id="table"></div>

    <script>
        var cols = [
            { title: "Cell 1", field: "c1", editor: "input" },
            { title: "Cell 2", field: "c2", editor: "input" }
        ];
        var data = [{}]

        var table = new Tabulator('#table', {
            columns: cols,
            data: data,
            tabEndNewRow: true
        })


    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Because of the error message I looked in the Edit.js file - here is the code for navigating into the created row.

```js
    keybindingNavigateNext(e){
        var cell = this.currentCell,
        newRow = this.options("tabEndNewRow");

        if(cell){
            if(!this.navigateNext(e)){
                if(newRow){
                    cell.getElement().firstChild.blur();

                    if(newRow === true){
                        newRow = this.table.addRow({})
                    }else{
                        if(typeof newRow == "function"){
                            newRow = this.table.addRow(newRow(cell.row.getComponent()))
                        }else{
                            newRow = this.table.addRow(Object.assign({}, newRow));
                        }
                    }

                    newRow.then(() => {
                        setTimeout(() => {
                            nav.next();
                        })
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am experiencing the same. I guess it must be a bug so I create new bug report for Tabulator **5.0.8** https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/3523

Working jsFiddle is here https://jsfiddle.net/radek/Lkah397y/4/

```
    var cols = [
        { title: "Cell 1", field: "c1", editor: "input" },
        { title: "Cell 2", field: "c2", editor: "input" }
    ];
    var data = [{}]

    var table = new Tabulator('#table', {
        columns: cols,
        data: data,
        tabEndNewRow: true
    })
```

**UPDATE**

a fix for this is in 5,1 branch and will be included in the next release